# How to fix Chromium 95 memory leak?

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, chromium, memory-leak

Using `Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)` causes memory leak while watching youtube, which leads to disk swap and eventually halts my desktop.

```
$ uname -a
Linux pc5 5.4.0-89-generic #100~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 29 10:59:42 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I had not such problem before, I've also tried the same version of Chrome, and go the same problem. So I guess has something to do with a bug in the new Chromium build.

I'm wondering if others have also experienced this problem? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it's not related to an extension you have installed?   I have no issues with that version of `chromium`, but I've had issues with extensions before with some version changes; so I remove extensions & add back slowly until I know which one is a problem & decide what I'll do (*some I stopped using; others I mitigated in various ways*).

Comment: Well, I don't use many addons, apart from `AdBlockPlus` and `YoutubeAdBlocker`. Could these be the culprits?

Comment: I don't know (*I don't use either*), but remove (or *disable*) them, restart the browser & see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I tried with a new brand new Chrome install with no extensions, but just  after a few minutes of watching youtube (wit ads) I see that  chrome consumes about 5GB of ram and it is going up.